# Send keys to background application

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pywin32, pywinauto

I am trying to send keys to an application running in the background. I want to send 'Alt+f+a' to the background application. I tried `type_keys('%fa')` from `pywinauto` but that brings the window to the foreground, I want it to remain in the background.

Here is a bit of what I currently have:

```
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(path=exePath)

# Open Save As
win = app.window(title_re=appTitle)
win.wait("enabled", timeout=60)
win.type_keys('%fa')    #Sends keys, but brings window to foreground
```

Using `type_keys('%fa', set_foreground=False)` will send the command to the active window. So, I am using VsCode as my text editor and 'Alt+f+a' gets sent there instead of the target application.

I have tried using `send_keystrokes()` instead of `type_keys()`, but this does not complete the command. It does send 'Alt+f' in the background but is not sending the 'a'. I have tried calling 'Alt+f' then 'Alt+a' immediately after (and with a time delay) but sending another 'Alt' just closes the opened file menu.

During my search I have seen `PostMessage()` from `win32gui` but have not been able to get that working.

Comment: Hmm... You may try `send_keystrokes("{VK_MENU DOWN}fa{VK_MENU UP}")` to hold Alt for 2 symbols and then release it.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept your solution? @VasilyRyabov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `win.send_keystrokes("{VK_MENU DOWN}fa{VK_MENU UP}")` to hold Alt for 2 symbols and then release it.

Answer (score 0):

try sending the [type_keys](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html#pywinauto.base_wrapper.BaseWrapper.type_keys) parameter set_foreground to False

something like this:

```
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(path=exePath)

# Open Save As
win = app.window(title_re=appTitle)
win.wait("enabled", timeout=60)
win.type_keys('%fa', set_foreground=False)
```

or try this method instead: [send_keystrokes](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper.send_keystrokes)
like the description says it send keystrokes silently ^^

Comment: That opened the file menu so 'Alt+f' worked, but it didn't go past that.

Comment: which one the type_keys set_foreground parameter or send_keystrokes method ?
I have edited my answer with an example for the set_foreground parameter

Comment: send_keystokes only gets to 'Alt+f' but does run in the background. type_keys completes the command but brings the window to the foreground.

Comment: even with the set_foreground=False ? I have edited my answer you can check it out now

Comment: Using set_foreground=False no longer sends the keys to the target app but instead to the active window. So it was performing 'Alt+f+a' in my text editor.